# accessing variables from js files to ts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, updates

Hi I'm trying to update an existing angular app from version 2 to 9, I'm starting by updating it to angular 4 then continuing later, I was able to update the packages that require updating, but now I'm getting an error that a variable is not defined
here is the app structure

I have `legend.component.js`

```
var LegendSingleton=function(() {
               ...
               createInstance
               ...
               getInstance
               ...
```

`main.component.js`

```
var myExtObject = {
               ...
               legend : LegendSingleton.getInstance()
               ...
```

then in `layoutindicateur.component.ts`

```
              ...
var myExtObject = require('../../../assets/geoFunction/main.component.js');
some use of myExtObject 
              ...
```

also in `angular-cli.json` i declared those js files in `scripts` :

```
...
"assets/geoFunction/component/legend.component.js",
...
"assets/geoFunction/main.component.js"
```

I'm getting error `Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: LegendSingleton is not defined`
I tried to import the legend js file in main js file using `var LegendSingleton = require('../geoFunction/component/legend.component.js');` but got error of `getInstance` not a function

Comment: Having the files in angular-cli.json is normally enough, no need to require anything

Answer (score 1):

You normally just need to add the files to your `angular-cli.json` files, in the `scripts` section.

Then, in your `layoutindicateur.component.ts` file, declare `myExtObject` below the angular imports

```
//import ....
declare let myExtObject: any;
```

Then use it in your component file

```
myExtObject.legend.legendFunction()
```

Comment: yeah i already added the files to ```angular-cli.json``` even when I use ```declare var/let myExtObject :any;``` i get the error ```Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: myExtObject is not defined```

Comment: Is it a runtime error? Can you show your component's code ?

Comment: I fixed it but adding all js files into ```index.html```  then ```declare var/let myExtObject :any;``` worked don't know why they weren't read from the ```angular-cli.json```